# How can I make Meteor templates available to targeted audiences via an URL?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I want to build a Blog, of sorts, with Meteor but, rather than just have a Blog such as platypus.meteor.com, I want to create a separate Meteor template for each Blog "post" and then send a link to select people such as "platypus.meteor.com/thispost"

In this way, the person would only see the post I intend them to see; to see others, they would have to guess at other values, such as "/thatpost", "/theotherpost" etc.

And in my case, if they stumbled across them, no big deal.

This is my plan:

Create one template at a time:

```
<template name="thispost">
    . . .
</template>
```

...and then allow access to that to whomever I apprise of its availability (that is, they simply enter the link I send them into their browser).

I don't know what sort of routing I need to set up; I'm open to either IronRouter or FlowRouter. At any rate, I want an URL like "platypus.meteor.com/thispost" (after a "meteor deploy platypus" of this project) to show the user the contents of that Template and nothing else.

So my question is: what do I have to do, routing-wise, to accomplish this?

Comment: Why even bother with different templates when you could just fetch the data using routing and feed it to a `showPost` template?

Comment: @Kyll: exactly. With IronRouter, then you'd just set up `Router.route("/:blog_post_title", {template: "blog_post", name: "blog_post"})`

Comment: @AutumnLeonard: In this case I *would* need a template named "blog_post" right?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Yes; it would make sense to me to have posts share a common template, but if that's impossible maybe Michel Floyd's answer below is more suitable.

Comment: @AutumnLeonard: Is this "(Router.route()" IronRouter? I'm leaning toward FlowRouter...

Comment: @AutumnLeonard: Never mind, I see you mention IronRouter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply:

```
Router.route("/:templateName/:postId",{
  template: this.params.templateName,
  data: function(){ return Posts.findOne({ _id: this.params.postId })
});
```

Then you can generically share any post with any template and have the template name appear right in the route.

Comment: All down but nine; set 'em up on the other alley, pard.